# How do I say that the tap water is back after it was cut off?

Tags: word-request, translation

Due to a severe drought hitting my country, we have tap water only twice a week.
So when the tap water is cut off and then it's back, how do I express this?

In my mother tongue, I can say that the water is back and it makes perfect sense. I want to know  how to say that in English.

Comment: "The water [supply] is back [on]."

Comment: The water is off, the water is back on, the water has been turned back on, the water is on again. There are tons of ways to say this.

Comment: It's kind of funny, that you wrote it exactly normally: "the tap water is cut off and then it's back" and then ask... how to say it.

Comment: @Sam Something might sound natural to me yet make no sense to a native speaker. That's why it's safer to ask.

Answer (score 2):

It makes sense in English too. Just say "the water is back" as you would normally say. English speakers will understand you given the context.